# I have an array of object and simple array with values, how can i add this value from array to each object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 43, 5];

const arrayofObj = [
  {
    key: 1,
    value: 3,
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    value: 10,
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    value: 30,
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    value: 30,
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    value: 30,
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    value: 30,
  },
];

// i only come up with that: 

const add = function(i) {
    arrayofobj[i].val = array1[i] 
}

add(2)

// but it as you know only adds up to one specific index, so how can i add this value to all elements ? thanks for any help :)
```

i want to have something like that:

```js
const arrayofobj = [
  {
    key:1,
    value:2,
    val: // array1 element that have exact same index
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little unclear about the expected result but you may be looking for something like that.

(Note that this works if the two arrays have the same length...)

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 43, 5];

const arrayofObj = [{
  key: 1,
  value: 3,
}, {
  key: 2,
  value: 10,
}, {
  key: 3,
  value: 20,
}, {
  id: 123,
  value: 30,
}];

const result = arrayofObj.map((o, i) => {
  return {
    ...o,
    val: array1[i]
  }
}); 

console.log(result)
```

Comment: yea that is exacly the result i was looking for, thanks for help mate, Best regards :)